# Wordpress taxonomy query, one string variable in terms array works one doesn't

Tags: php, wordpress

I am building a grid in Wordpress that has custom taxonomy terms that will be used as filters. I have been working with using variables in `'terms' => array()`. One type of variable works and one doesn't.

Here is the query:

```
$args = array(
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'post_type' => 'plant',
    'orderby' => 'name',
    'order' => 'ASC',
    'tax_query' => array(
        'relation' => 'AND',
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'trail_location',
            'field' => 'slug',
            'terms' => array($trailLocationList),  
        ),
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'bloom_time',
            'field' => 'slug',
            'terms' => array($bloomTime),
        )
    )
);
$loop = new WP_Query( $args );
```

I can convert a query string value to a var and it works:

```
$bloomTime = $_GET['bloom_time']; 
'terms' => array($bloomTime).
```

Static values work: `'terms' => array('loc1', 'loc2', 'loc3')`.

What doesn't work is when a variable is created from an array of existing taxonomy slugs.

```
$terms = get_terms("trail_location");
$count = count($terms);
if ( $count > 0 ){
    foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
      $trailLocationList[] = $term->slug;
    }
}
$trailLocationList = implode("', '",$trailLocationList);
$trailLocationList = "'".$trailLocationList."'";
```

The var outputs the exact string I need as used above in the static example `('loc1', 'loc2', 'loc3')`, but for some reason the query doesn't work. I've tested and both vars are strings.

Comment: a string with commas in it is NOT an array

Comment: if you deleted the last 2 lines it should be fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as per my comment, a string with commas in it is NOT an array.
Remove the implode step and use the $trailLocationList array as the term:

```
$terms = get_terms("trail_location");
$count = count($terms);
if ( $count > 0 ){
    foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
      $trailLocationList[] = $term->slug;
    }
}
/* why?? dont do this
$trailLocationList = implode("', '",$trailLocationList);
$trailLocationList = "'".$trailLocationList."'";
*/

$args = array(
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'post_type' => 'plant',
    'orderby' => 'name',
    'order' => 'ASC',
    'tax_query' => array(
        'relation' => 'AND',
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'trail_location',
            'field' => 'slug',
            //'terms' => array($trailLocationList),  wrong
            'terms' => $trailLocationList //correct
        ),
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'bloom_time',
            'field' => 'slug',
            'terms' => array($bloomTime),
        )
    )
);
$loop = new WP_Query( $args );
```

Comment: Works! I misunderstood what you were getting at in your previous comment. I am still a bit confused as to why I can place the static comma separated list in there and it works?

Comment: you are confused between writing php code and displaying information i think. your code was doing the equivilent of this: terms=>array("'one','two','three'") notice the extra double quotes. php is weakly typed but it wont just interpret random strings